# Run Multiple test suite in same jsession using Robot Framework : Python

Tags: robotframework

I have to run multiple test suite in same session and same session cookie in robot framework , since i want to test whether the url is working for all the nodes for doing that i have to hit url with same session cookies , which cannot be set explicitly . So is there any way i can run all the Test Suite in same session . ?  or i can run all the test suite in same browser on different tabs .

So the code i tried runs each test suite on each browser page there by end of one browser run deleting session and session cookie created and the new test run will have new cookie and session , so that was the problem so when doing it , it test each test suite with different cookie . but i want it to be tested in same session and cookie .

Can anyone help me on this , this is second time posting this question in Stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this works the same way for opening tabs, but you can make test suite setup. Declare your environment and this environment will be shared in all the tests in the suite.

I used it with ssh, but same analogy should work in your case. If you run this code, you can see that the ssh connection exists in both tests, but is only initialized in the suite setup.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary
Suite Setup       Run Keyword    SSH Login    ${your_host}    ${host_name}    ${host_pass}
*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    ${output}=    SSHLibrary.Get Connections
    Log    ${output}
Test 2
    ${output}=    SSHLibrary.Get Connections
    Log    ${output}
*** Keywords ***
SSH Login
    [Arguments]    ${your_host}    ${host_name}    ${host_pass}
    SSHLibrary.Open Connection     ${your_host}
    SSHLibrary.Login    ${host_name}    ${host_pass}
```

you can read more about suite setup and teardown here
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown

Answer (score 0):

For sharing a session, you can just use the `Suite Setup` to create the session and then use this session for the following tests, for example, you share a session named **mysession** :

```
*** Settings ***

Library             RequestsLibrary
Library             Collections
...

Suite Setup         Create session   mysession  ${my_application_url}
...
```

Keywords

```
*** Keywords ***
        
Login
    [Arguments]    ${username}    ${password}
      ${header}=  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json
      ${body}=    Create Dictionary  username=${username}       password=${password}
      ${resp}=    Post Request    mysession       /login     headers=${header}   data=${body}
      Log         ${resp.content}
        
Get all users
 #Don't create session again
  ${resp}=                    Get Request             mysession               /users
   Log                         ${resp.text}
```

Tests

```
*** Test Cases ***

    Test login
        login    tester      tester

    Test get users
        Get all users
```

In this way, you can do login first, then use the same session in the next test. you could do a `teardown` to logout if you need. Then the cookie also can be found in `${myresponse.cookies}` but the format is CookieJar. I don't use `Selenium2Library` but I think in this lib, you don't need to parse the CookieJar manually. then if you want to share the cookie, you can just set a global variable for this cookie. There is one similar question: [Set session cookie across the test suites in Robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114335/set-session-cookie-across-the-test-suites-in-robot-framework)